# Has quagga been removed from 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

new install of 22.04

```
root@shrike:~# apt-cache search quagga
frr - FRRouting suite of internet protocols (BGP, OSPF, IS-IS, ...)
bgpdump - Translate binary zebra/quagga/MRT files into readable output
mrtparse - read and analyze the MRT format data (utilities)
netscript-2.4 - Linux 2.4/2.6/3.x router/firewall/VM host network config system.
puppet-module-icann-quagga - Puppet module for Quagga
python3-mrtparse - read and analyze the MRT format data (Python 3.x module)
smcroute - static multicast router daemon
```

There's actually instructions online for installing quagga, which just say apt-install, however I'm guessing they've just been copied from 20.04, because quagga is no longer in the supported packages.

Is there another repo I need for quagga now, or should I be using another packaging system such as snap ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. quagga was [removed from and did not ship in Ubuntu 22.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quagga/+publishinghistory). It is replaced by frr, which is a fork.

quagga was [reported to have a "dead upstream" and have open security issues](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1000216).

More information can be found in [Ubuntu's frr MIR bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/frr/+bug/1951834).

Short answer: use frr instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.   Unfortunately last time I looked at FRR the OSPF implementation was incomplete and buggy, I hope it has improved :)